# Binding not changing selected value of Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have `ComboBox`

```
  <ComboBox Height="23" Name="DriveSelection" Width="120"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FixedDrives}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding DriveSelection_SelectionChanged }"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding DriveIsEnabled}"
                              />
```

In my `viewModel` it looks like this:

```
    public PathSelectionPageViewModel(PathSelectionPage _page)
    {
        this.page = _page;
        this.root = Path.GetPathRoot(App.Instance.PathManager.InstallRoot).ToUpperInvariant();
        this.DriveSelection = this.root;
        this.DriveSelection_SelectionChanged = new DriveInfo(this.root);
        this.DriveIsEnabled = App.Instance.PathManager.CanModify;
        this.RunText = App.Instance.InstallationProperties.InstallationScript.Installer.Name;

    }
public ObservableCollection<DriveInfo> FixedDrives
{
     get
        {
            if (this.fixedDrives != null)
                return this.fixedDrives;
            this.fixedDrives = new ObservableCollection<DriveInfo>(Enumerable.Where<DriveInfo>((IEnumerable<DriveInfo>)DriveInfo.GetDrives(), (Func<DriveInfo, bool>)(driveInfo => driveInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)));
            return this.fixedDrives;
        }
    }

     public DriveInfo DriveSelection_SelectionChanged
    {
        get
        {
           return this.driveSelection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == this.driveSelection)
                return;
            this.driveSelection = value;
            UpdatePathManager();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("DriveSelection_SelectionChanged");
        }
    }
```

As You can see I'm binding list of hardrives to the combobox as `itemSource`. And then If needed I'm changing  the selected item in this line:

```
this.DriveSelection_SelectionChanged = new DriveInfo(this.root);
```

Eg. this.root is pointing at drive `E` so combobox selection should change to E but now its still hanging at `C`.
My bindings are wrong or error is elsewhere?

Comment: `DriveInfo` does not override `Equals` so it will be compared by reference. Pick one `DriveInfo` from the `fixedDrives` list instead of creating new instance

Comment: Could you post a snippet  in which fragment I should modify my code?

Comment: try something like `this.DriveSelection_SelectionChanged = FixedDrives.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == this.Root)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you create with new at this line

```
this.DriveSelection_SelectionChanged = new DriveInfo(this.root);
```

isn't contained in the FixedDrivers list you databind to ItemsSource. If you select one of the items in the FixedDrivers the right item will be selected

```
var selectedItem = this.FixedDrives.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == this.Root);
this.DriveSelection_SelectionChanged = selectedItem;
```